# Error in rmarkdown: In get_engine(options$engine)

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

I making a beamer presentation on Rmarkdown. I have never faced an issue/error like this before. All the necessary packages are loaded.

```
---
title: 'Class 1'
author: "Eric"
date: "27/10/2022"
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
fontsize: 7pt
---
```

```
Error in happiness %>% filter(year == 1998 | year == 2004) : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
In addition: Warning message:
In get_engine(options$engine) :
  Unknown language engine 'packages' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).
```

I have downloaded the engines software and added to the following in the set-up chunk:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::knit_engines$set(Racket = function(options) {
  code <- paste(options$code, collapse = '\n')
  out  <- system2(
    'Racket',  c('-e', shQuote(code)), stdout = TRUE
  )
  knitr::engine_output(options, code, out)
})
```

Comment: You should post a complete document, including the YAML.  Only include the minimal text necessary to trigger the error and warning.

Comment: The error is not related to `get_engine`. For get_engine you only get a warning. From the error message `could not find function "%>%"` I would guess that you missed to include `library(dplyr)` in your Rmd.

Comment: @user2554330Can you please tell what is YAML?

Comment: @stefan I have put ```library(tidyverse)``` in my Rmd

Comment: @Eric, "yaml" is "yet another markup language", it is everything at the very top of an Rmd doc that specifies things like title, author, date, and other parameters. It is preceded and followed by `---\n` (that is, `---` then a newline), and must be included before any actual Rmd content. You probably have it without knowing that it is "yaml".

Comment: @r2evans I have added that to the question